# Какой максимально мощный процессор можно поставить на сокет "rpga-989"

Tags: процессор, intel

Сейчас стоит Intel Core I5-2410m, и он не такой слабый, но если вспомнить что сейчас 2022 год, то можно сказать что уже слабый. Какой можно максимально мощный процц поставить на этот сокет?   Тип: Ноутбук

Comment: у меня i5-2500 и никаких проблем не испытываю

Comment: Можно сказать, что слабый. А можно не говорить. Слабый для чего?